# How to look for items in an arraycollection from a innerJoined entity in dql?

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I want to select visits form users. The visits should contain tag names that are occuring in an array I am passing to dql.

Till now this is what I have:

```
    // select the user database
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('u')
        ->from('MyBundle:User', 'u');
        ->innerJoin('u.visits', 'v');
        ->innerJoin('v.tags', 't');
```

Now I want to look for visits that have tags ('t') with names i.e. 'VIP' **AND** 'Employee' **AND** ... etc. These names are dynamic, **the array could be any length** .

't' has a property name and is an arraycollection from 'v' 
'v' is an arraycollection form 'u'

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `WHERE IN` statement, passing as the parameter the array of names.

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('t.name', array('VIP', 'Employee', '...')));
```

Comment: this is close, but not quite yet the solution. This will check whether one of the tag names exists in the array. Let's say I have a visit with the Tag 'VIP' and the Tag 'Employee', above statement finds it more then enough if one of tags occurs in the array, while it strictly should look for visits who have both (or more) tags assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

i solved through recursion

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('u')
        ->from('MyBundle:User', 'u');
    $qb ->innerJoin('u.visits', 'v');
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('v.id', $this->getVisitDQL($qb, $visitData, $tagCounter)));
```

```
public function getVisitDQL(QueryBuilder $qb, $data, $counter) {

    $tag = $data['tags'][$counter];
    $tagName = $tag['content'];

    $qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb2
        ->select('v'.$counter.'.id')
        ->from('MyBundle:Visit', 'v'.$counter)
        ->innerJoin('v'.$counter.'.tags', 'vt'.$counter)
        ->where($qb2->expr()->eq('vt'.$counter.'.name',':vtag_'.$counter ));

    $qb->setParameter(':vtag_'.$counter, $tagName);

    // if were not processing the last filter, continue recursion
    if ($counter != (count($data['tags'])-1)) {
        $qb2->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('v'.$counter.'.id', $this->getVisitDQL($qb, $data, $counter + 1)));
    }

    return $qb2->getDQL();
}
```